# journal/newspaper/magazine in/on/of/about a topic

Tags: prepositions, synonyms

1. What's the difference between journal, newspaper and magazine? I read about this, I found explanations where they say "journal" is for academical publications only, otherwhere they say it can be used just like "newspaper" or "magazine". What's right? (And what are the connotations of the word journal?)
2. Is a journal in / on / of / about some topic?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Asquir. We expect people to do some research before they ask a question. If your research does not answer your question, you should include details fo their research (links, etc) and explain what you are confused about. You have clearly done some research for question 1 but you haven't provided links so we can't see why it's still not clear to you, and it doesn't look like you have done any research at all for the second question. Here is a good place to look for definitions of words: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/journal. Note the word **professional**

Answer (score 0):

*All definitions below were discovered through a Google search.*

One of the dictionary definitions for "journal" when used as a noun is as follows:

> a newspaper or magazine that deals with a particular subject or professional activity.

This definition of journal implies that the editorial piece must relate to a **specific** event or topic, such as a medical journal.

(Personal opinion: You could also say that a journal is considered to be a more "serious" editorial.)

For example, "The New England Journal of Medicine is a weekly medical journal published by the Massachusetts Medical Society. It is among the most prestigious peer-reviewed medical journals as well as the oldest continuously published one."

Their website can be found [here](http://www.nejm.org/). Within it, you will find that every topic or section relates to medical health.

---

One of the dictionary definitions for "newspaper" when used as a noun is as follows:

> a printed publication (usually issued daily or weekly) consisting of folded unstapled sheets and containing news, feature articles, advertisements, and correspondence.

This definition of newspaper implies that the editorial piece would usually come in a specific form, described as "folded unstapled sheets."

Within a newspaper, depending on which one, you may find global news, local news, sports, comics, job listings, and things of that nature. It's extremely general.

An example of a newspaper that had a specific scope of information is The Bulletin. "The Bulletin was an Australian magazine first published in Sydney on 31 January 1880. The publication's focus was politics and business, with some literary content, and editions were often accompanied by cartoons and other illustrations."

---

One of the dictionary definitions for "magazine" when used as a noun is as follows:

> a periodical publication containing articles and illustrations, typically covering a particular subject or area of interest.

This definition of magazine implies that the editorial piece implies that a magazine can be character by having numerous articles and pictures, that all should relate to the same topic, or a number of related topics.

While this may sound similar to the definition of journal, they are different in the sense that:

1. A journal covers one topic, and that topic only. It does not spend much time discussing related topics.
2. A magazine is usually something that you subscribe to, and receive many different editions of it through the mail.

One magazine in particular that is a great example is *Newsweek.* "Newsweek provides in-depth analysis, news and opinion about international issues, technology, business, culture and politics."

Their website can be found [here](http://www.newsweek.com/).